Why does the KJV translate Judges 17:6 and Judges 21:25 differently?
Judges 17:6, and the final verse in the book, 21:25, each say:

בַּיָּמִים הָהֵם אֵין מֶלֶךְ בְּיִשְׂרָאֵל אִישׁ הַיָּשָׁר בְּעֵינָיו יַעֲשֶׂה׃

The King James version translates these two verses differently though:

17:6:   In those days [there was] no king in Israel, [but] every man did [that which was] right in his own eyes.
21:25: In those days [there was] no king in Israel, every man did [that which was] right in his own eyes.

Is there any commentary about why the translators would have supplied "but" for the first verse but not for the second?
(This is not asking for immediate personal opinions, but for existing publications.)

Just put this down to another of the many inexplicable idiosyncratic quicks of the KJV.

Different passages of scripture were handled, in the writing of the KJV, by different translators. It is interesting that two aspects of the statement appear with the addition of 'but'. There are two meanings can be placed on the text. Perhaps the translators were uncertain of the interpretation and supplied both ?
